# Скажите, запятая во фразе ставится?

Tags: пунктуация

Невозможно определить, что внутри.

Comment: Нужна одна запятая, вы ее поставили верно.

Comment: Зачем коротенький ответ, где коммент должен быть?

Answer (score 1):

Ставится. У нас сложноподчинённое предложение.

Главное: невозможно определить;

придаточное: (находится) внутри;

подчинительный союз: что.